# JQueryUI dialog maxWidth insuficcient

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, css

I have a jqueryui dialog defined with maxWidth.

```
$("#myDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 'auto',
        maxWidth: 1000,
        height: 'auto',
        position: [250, 50],
        close: function() {
            $("#myViewer").empty();
            someStuff();
        }
    });
```

The maxWidth works as intended when I resize the form with the resize handle. But the form contains tabs (that turn out on two rows) and other stuff which tries to occupy all of the given space.

When I open the form it hits the right browser edge. As I move the window with the mouse to the left, the dialog is automatically resized as there are more space available to the right.
However, it doesn't stop at maxWidth.

If i grab the resize handle when larger than maxWidth, it resizes back to maxWidth.

Also, the titlebar of the dialog isn't the width of the dialog until it's resized by either changing the viewport size or using the resize handle.

**Here's a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/CarlR/PvE3P/22/**

I hope the description is clear enough. You can try it out on the jsfiddle. The problem is when the dialog is shown the first time.
(I'm using google chrome btw)

Comment: Could you post a link to it, or some html? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a jsfiddle of what I think you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/PvE3P/41/. I tied into the $(window).resize() and dynamically update the dialog width depending on the window width. I hope this helps!

EDIT:

I've update the jsfiddle to work a little more seamlessly. http://jsfiddle.net/PvE3P/42/

Answer (score 1):

You can do some judge in jquery code, something like this

```
$("#showDialog").click(function(){
    $("#myDialog").dialog("open");
    var width = $(".ui-dialog").width();
    if(width>400){
        $(".ui-dialog").css({'width':'400px'});
        //fixed if width > 400px, defined width always as 400px 
    }
});
```

See:
http://jsfiddle.net/PvE3P/23/

Comment: @Carl R, so what is your purpose want? what is the min-width? see something update in `http://jsfiddle.net/PvE3P/25/`.

Comment: Looks promising... I'll run some tests here. :)

Comment: The missing auto-width is the problem right now. The dialog needs to occupy as much space as necessary or the maxWidth. Exactly like width: 'auto' works.

Comment: Sorry, still not quite know what you need. `The dialog needs to occupy as much space as necessary or the maxWidth` are you mean when the dialog open, the width is `400px`(max-width), then the client could adjust the width by auto(from max-width 400px to 0)?

Comment: In reality, it's a form with tabs that are all ajax loaded. The form cannot be larger than 1000px because it breaks the layout, but it should use as much screen estate as necessary (with regards to the content) and possible (with regard to browser window size). This means that when the dialog loads it will be somewhere around 800-1000px wide usually and the user can resize it. Currently it all works fine except that when the user drags the dialog to the left, the first time, it grows on the right hand without limit. But 400px was easier to display in jsfiddle.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I can not meet your request, last update in http://jsfiddle.net/PvE3P/40/

Answer (score 1):

```
.ui-dialog {
   ...
   max-width: 400px;
}
```